# grouping a list to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Version: python 2.7**

Given list looks like this:

```
[ ['a', '1'], ['b','2'], ['c','3'], ['a', '11'], ['b','2'], ['c','31'], ['a', '1'], ['b','22'], ['c','3d'] ]
```

output should be in json format as follows:

```
  [{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3"
 }, {
    "a": "11",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "31"
 }, {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "22",
    "c": "3d"
 }]
```

I tried lambdas,

```
list( map(str.strip(), line.split(':') for line in liness)
```

I was wondering how to get it grouped to get the above json format?

Comment: Your sample snippet suggests the list is actually a string, and furthermore where does the `str` come from? Additionally, we cannot help without knowing more about the input list format; is it always groups of three, in which case the problem becomes rather simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the data you mentioned as example, following code will work.

```
[dict(x) for x in zip(*[iter(z)]*3)]
```

If you add extra `('d', 4)` at the after every occurrence of `c` in the list, you can replace `3` with `4` in that case.

For everything else, we need more data and your sample code as proof of effort to begin with.